# Android асинхронная запрос ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, асинхронность

При старте Activity(в методе onCreate) отправляется запрос на сервер, с которого приходит количество элементов-фрагментов для ViewPager. ViewPagerAdapter Требует переопределения метода getCount(), чтобы возвратить количество элементов во ViewPager. Вопрос в том, как решить проблему с подгрузкой, потому что метод getCount() у адаптера вызывается раньше, чем успеет прийти ответ с сервера. Среди вариантов решения был - сохранять при ответе с сервера в SharedPreferences, а в getCount() возвращать это сохраненное значение. Но получалось, что при первом старте считывать нечего. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращать 0 если данные еще не подгрузились. И потом как подгрузятся вызывать у адаптерa `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Или сделать `ProgressBar`, который будет крутиться пока данные для `ViewPager`'a не подгрузятся и только потом создавать адаптер и сетить во вью пейджер.